# How to create MyEclipse shortcuts to open multiple workspaces ?

Tags: eclipse, workspace, myeclipse, shortcut-file

I have two different MyEclipse workspaces containing a different set of project. I was hoping to avoid having to switch between the two by creating shortcuts which directly open the workspaces.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From **[here](http://help.eclipse.org/help21/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209789/starting-eclipse-w-specific-workspace)**:

Use the following command-line argument:

```
-data your_workspace_location
```

For example,

```
-data c:\users\Soumyaansh\myworkspace
```

Try adding the above parameter to the `Target` field of the MyEclipse shortcut like so :

[image]

Now created a second copy of this shortcut and just change the path after `-data` to that of the second workspace. If there are spaces in the path then enclose the path in double quotes.

For example, the target field of my shortcut looks like this :

`C:\dev\springsource\sts\STS.exe -data "C:\dev\workspace-matm-STS-1.6.0_30-64Bit"`

Yours should look something like :

`"C:\Program Files\MyEclipse\MyEclipse.exe" -data "C:\dev\workspace-matm-STS-1.6.0_30-64Bit"`

This can be used for any Eclipse based distribution like STS, MyEclipse etc.

Comment: thanks it really helped me a lot , i had wasted a lot of time figuring out  :)

Comment: @Soumyaansh, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png.

Comment: Is this the same for Galileo

Answer (score -1):

create one shortcut on your office toolbar with workspace A and another shortcut on taskbar and with workspace B then you can acess both the worksheets at a time