# How to change the default workspace location in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, location, default, workspace, zend-studio

This might be the most embarrassing question I've ever had to ask anyone. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the default workspace location in Zend Studio 9.0.3 (OS: Windows 7 x64). I've used google extensively for the last full hour and I've manually traversed the entire Zend Studio preferences page (or at least I think so). Also, there's this mysteriously looking file called `config.ini` in `%Zend Studio installation folder%\configuration\` that has this line in it:

> osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace

And no matter how creatively I try to rewrite that line or completely remove it, I can't get Zend Studio to stop digging in my "users" home directory. So, here's the problem illustrated in colors:

[image: Zend Studio default workspace location]

Whenever I create a new local PHP project, I want that default location to be something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the Workspace with

```
File > Switch Workspace > Other
```

Also see [Starting Eclipse w/ Specific Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209789/starting-eclipse-w-specific-workspace)

Once you have switched (created a new) workspace, you can delete the old one by going to

```
Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces
```

Comment: lol, so It was that easy huh. Took the liberty to add some post-instructions to your set. Thanx Gordon.