# How to make eclipse refer to workspace in the same folder as exe file?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to make eclipse refer to workspace in the same folder as eclipse.exe file without asking me every time. I use eclipse on usb stick on several computers (different labs around campus + my own laptop), and drive letter always changes, so is there a way to make eclipse... more portable?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12380842/900130) and try to set the property `osgi.instance.area.default` to `"."`

Comment: @Zoltán That changes the current directory but not the location of the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer about [starting Eclipse with a specific workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209789/starting-eclipse-w-specific-workspace)

There is a command-line argument `-data` you can give Eclipse for the location of the workspace.  You could create a batch file called 'runeclipse.bat' and give it the current directory as the location of the workspace.  I would create a subdirectory named 'workspace' though.

```
eclipse.exe -data .\workspace
```

A better idea would be to edit the `eclipse.ini`, which is in the same directory as the executable, and put the -data argument there. Make sure the -data argument appears *before* any JVM arguments

For example, here is my eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

I would add the -data argument like so, I've left empty lines to show what was added since there is no HTML or Markdown formatting in a code block, remember that the blank lines should not be in the actual `eclipse.ini` file.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-data
.\workspace     

-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

Comment: editing eclipse.ini sounds like an interesting idea, but can you specify how to do that, please? and I do use a sub-directory "workplace".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turns out if you add -data .\workspace in one line, it makes no changes.