# Eclipse Juno get crashed after Splash screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

My eclipse was working properly, but all of a sudden when i restarted my PC, it stopped working. Now, it is just show splash screen and then disappear.

From log file I got the exception below:

```
!SESSION 2014-06-24 10:41:35.291 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file D:\and_workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-06-24 10:43:13.576

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-06-24 10:43:13.576
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.logError(PluginDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.throwException(PluginDescriptor.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.doPluginActivation(PluginDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.PluginDescriptor.getPlugin(PluginDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPlugin(Platform.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.InitLegacyPreferences.init(InitLegacyPreferences.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService$5.run(PreferencesService.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getNodes(PreferencesService.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.getBoolean(PreferencesService.java:477)
    at com.aptana.usage.PingStartup.earlyStartup(PingStartup.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-06-24 10:43:13.646
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.ui.cxx.Startup.registerListeners(Startup.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.ui.cxx.Startup.earlyStartup(Startup.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-06-24 10:43:13.647
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.ui.cxx.Startup.registerListeners(Startup.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.ui.cxx.Startup.earlyStartup(Startup.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-06-24 10:43:13.647
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformLogWriter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Now I don't know where is the issue. I want to use same work space, don't want to create another. Creating new workspace solves this issue, but that is not what I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash ( deleting `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` )

Comment: if this problem is related to Workspace.. goto settings and select workspace again and restart eclipse..

Comment: @Prag's How i can able to change work space if i am not able to change the workspace?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan deleting that file will effect on my workspace? Will it delete any project from workspace?

Comment: no @iDroidExplorer, i didn't test but as you can see in that link and 3 other link that I've searched all say this answer. ( you can search about `null exception statushandlerregistry.java:72` )

Comment: @shayam purvatan please put your answer in a manner that i can accept it. its resolved my issue without changing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How i can able to change work space if i am not able to change the workspace? –

You can specify it in the command line:

```
eclipse.exe -clean -data /path/to/new/workspace
```

You can modify the `eclipse.ini`: see [FAQ Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?)

```
-data 
<workspace-path>
```

As mentioned in "[How to make eclipse refer to workspace in the same folder as exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22072735/6309)"

> Make sure the `-data` argument appears before any JVM arguments

That way, you don't touch/delete anything from your old workspace, and can still re-import existing projects.

Answer (score 7):

you can delete following file as i said in comment to solve your problem:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench
```

[Source of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash)