# how to open eclipse with specified workspace using java program

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I tried to open eclipse with particular workspace using following program but its not working.

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("eclipse.exe \"D:\\Research_&_development\"");
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209789/starting-eclipse-w-specific-workspace. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-data path` to specify the workspace location.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open eclipse by your code:

```
  class openEclipse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("F:\\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\eclipse.exe -data D:\\new");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want Eclipse to open a specific workspace from the command line or a shell execution, you can use the `-data path\to\workspace` argument.

In your case, you can do:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("eclipse.exe", "-data \"Research_&_development\"");
```

However, I recommend using absolute pathways in general; you don't have to, but I allows you to easily locate folders in the future.